# log4j2.xml SMTP appender get .war context

Tags: tomcat, log4j2, smtpappender

We are sending alert emails out on the fatal log level. But we want to get the context name dynamically.

we are using the same war file for different context. We just rename the war file. So we need a generic solution in the .xml file. Best in the subject line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Web Lookup` feature provided by `log4j2`. It allows to access `context path` of the web application using `${web:contextPath}` syntax. Your configuration file would look like -

```
<SMTP name="Mail" subject="FATAL - ${web:contextPath}" to="errors@logging.apache.org" from="test@logging.apache.org"
          smtpHost="localhost" smtpPort="25" bufferSize="50">
```

Check more details of `Web Lookup` [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#WebLookup)

Comment: can you specify what didn't work ? It means you are getting "FATAL - ${web:contextPath}" as string in subject ?

Comment: Can you also try using "FATAL - $${web:contextPath}"

Comment: Yes correct., both cases gave back the actual definition as string. What additional includes do I have to do ? Is it only log4j-web ?